# append special url end of my website urls

Tags: php, urls

I have wired problem. when I checked my Google Webmaster tools I saw I have many errors in my crawl tab and I don't know why this happening and why Google crawl those URLs.for example appending Contact-Us URL in my product URL.Can you help how solve this problem? I tried to solve this problem in my theme but I could not do anything .

Answer (score 0):

its very likely that somewhere in your theme, perhaps in your navigation or footer, you are linking something like 
`<a href="Contact-Us">` 
which will then link to the subdirectory.
You need to find those issues and fix it  with something like

```
<a href="/Contact-Us">
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/Contact-Us">
```

Without seeing code, it's hard to tell though.
Have you done a view source on your product page?